# Active nav menu items for the index page

Tags: jquery, css

I am able to pick up the URLs of any of my pages and set an 'active' state on the menu item when the user is on that page to change the style of the main menu nav link. However, when the user is on the homepage they are all being set so I am wondering how I can caveat this and not show the active state on all of the links and just on `/` (root)

```
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('.navbar .tabs ul li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('is-active');
        }
    })
});
```

It is probably something ever so simple yet JQuery isn't my strongest language.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

The code below searches for the href of the active page in the list elements < a >. Then adds the class "active" with addClass('active') to the active pages < a > so that you can now call it via CSS. Put this code in the head of your html file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.navbar .tabs ul li a').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass('active'); $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can now add your css conditions like changing the color:

```
.navbar .tabs ul li a {
    color:            #F8F8F8;
    background-color: #4f81bd;
}
```

Comment: That is perfect, I get what you are doing here over what I have attempted.